# Why would a cruiser in Stellaris fail to upgrade to the proper class how can I fix it?

Tags: stellaris

I asked a question about ship upgrading in Stellaris [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320681/67184) and learned that ships will upgrade to the latest design or the latest design with their name. I'm now trying to upgrade ships of one class (call it Class A) to a new class (call it Class B). I have only created one new class, Class B, but the ships I currently have of that class will not properly upgrade, even if other ships in the fleet will upgrade to new classes properly.

Are there any reasons why this would be happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: As the current answer says, if you still have Class A as a design, the current Class A ships will not upgrade to Class B. If you haven't, try deleting Class A

Answer (score 2):

You could try to delete the Class A design.

Go to the `Ship Designer` screen, move the mouse cursor over the design, then click the trash icon.

Comment: Also, if the Class A ships are the result of an event (example, as a present from a fallen empire) you will never be able to modify them.